# loop overrunning first loop

Tags: excel, vba

My code keeps running past the next cell to the next column loops, can anyone help with this? the main aim is to  highlight an entire range with Input Rng and to read a red value in each of the columns and return the register number to the left in the offset of the output column For each column of each cell.

```
ObtainSCEs()
Dim InputRng As Range
Dim OutputRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range

xTitleID = "ObtainSCE"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("select data Range:", xTitleID, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set OutputRng = Application.InputBox("select output Range:", xTitleID, Type:=8)
Dim C As Long
C = 0
Dim B As Long
B = InputRng.Columns.Count
Dim A As Long
A = 1
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Column As Range
    For Each Column In InputRng
        For Each Cell In Column
           If Cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
               If Len(OutputRng.Offset(0, 0)) > 0 Then
               OutputRng.Offset(0, C).Value = OutputRng.Offset(0, C).Value & ","
               OutputRng.Offset(0, C).Value = OutputRng.Offset(0, C) & Cell.Offset(0, -1 - C).Value
               Else
                OutputRng.Offset(0, C) = Cell.Offset(0, -1 - C).Value
            End If
            End If
        Next Cell

        Next Column


End Sub
```

I have a second code that i tried using a different approach but it keeps running the first column continuously. Shown below

```
  Sub ObtainSCEs()
Dim InputRng As Range
Dim OutputRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range

xTitleID = "ObtainSCE"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("select data Range:", xTitleID, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set OutputRng = Application.InputBox("select output Range:", xTitleID, Type:=8)
Dim C As Long
C = 0
Dim B As Long
B = InputRng.Columns.Count
Dim A As Long
A = 0
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Column As Range

    For n = 1 To 5
    InputRng.Columns(n).Select

        For Each Cell In InputRng.Columns.Cells
           If Cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
               If Len(OutputRng.Offset(0, 0)) > 0 Then
               OutputRng.Offset(0, C) = OutputRng.Offset(0, C).Value & ","
               OutputRng.Offset(0, C) = OutputRng.Offset(0, C) & Cell.Offset(0, -1 - C).Value
               Else
                OutputRng.Offset(0, C) = Cell.Offset(0, -1 - C).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next Cell
        C = C + 1
    Next n


End Sub
```

This is the code i'm currently using to do this, right now i'm manually selecting all 6 columns but i want to select 1 entire range then split the range into its respective columns.

```
Sub GetSCE()
Application.Volatile True
Dim Rng As Range
Dim InputRng1 As Range, OutputRng As Range
Dim InputRng2 As Range, InputRng3 As Range
Dim InputRng4 As Range, InputRng5 As Range
Dim InputRng6 As Range
Dim Cell As Range
Dim sev1 As Integer
sev1 = 1
Dim sev2 As Integer
sev2 = 2
Dim sev3 As Integer
sev3 = 3
Dim sev4 As Integer
sev4 = 4
Dim sev5 As Integer
sev5 = 5
Dim sev6 As Integer
sev6 = 6
xTitleID = "ObtainSCE"
Set InputRng1 = Application.Selection
Set InputRng1 = Application.InputBox("Select Data Range1:", xTitleID, InputRng1.Address, Type:=8)
Set InputRng2 = Application.InputBox("Select Data Range2:", xTitleID, Type:=8)
Set InputRng3 = Application.InputBox("Select Data Range3:", xTitleID, Type:=8)
Set InputRng4 = Application.InputBox("Select Data Range4:", xTitleID, Type:=8)
Set InputRng5 = Application.InputBox("Select Data Range5:", xTitleID, Type:=8)
Set InputRng6 = Application.InputBox("Select Data Range6:", xTitleID, Type:=8)
Set OutputRng1 = Application.InputBox("Select Starting Cells:", xTitleID, Type:=8)
Set OutputRng2 = Application.InputBox("Select Starting Cells:", xTitleID, Type:=8)
Set OutputRng3 = Application.InputBox("Select Starting Cells:", xTitleID, Type:=8)
Set OutputRng4 = Application.InputBox("Select Starting Cells:", xTitleID, Type:=8)
Set OutputRng5 = Application.InputBox("Select Starting Cells:", xTitleID, Type:=8)
Set OutputRng6 = Application.InputBox("Select Starting Cells:", xTitleID, Type:=8)
    For Each Cell In InputRng1
        If Cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            If Len(OutputRng1) > 0 Then OutputRng1.Value = OutputRng1.Value & ","
            OutputRng1.Value = OutputRng1.Value & Cell.Offset(0, -sev1).Value
            Else
        End If
    Next Cell
    For Each Cell In InputRng2
        If Cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            If Len(OutputRng2) > 0 Then OutputRng2.Value = OutputRng2.Value & ","
            OutputRng2.Value = OutputRng2.Value & Cell.Offset(0, -sev2).Value
            Else
        End If
    Next Cell
        For Each Cell In InputRng3
        If Cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            If Len(OutputRng3) > 0 Then OutputRng3.Value = OutputRng3.Value & ","
            OutputRng3.Value = OutputRng3.Value & Cell.Offset(0, -sev3).Value
            Else
        End If
    Next Cell
        For Each Cell In InputRng4
        If Cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            If Len(OutputRng4) > 0 Then OutputRng4.Value = OutputRng4.Value & ","
            OutputRng4.Value = OutputRng4.Value & Cell.Offset(0, -sev4).Value
            Else
        End If
    Next Cell
        For Each Cell In InputRng5
        If Cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            If Len(OutputRng5) > 0 Then OutputRng5.Value = OutputRng5.Value & ","
            OutputRng5.Value = OutputRng5.Value & Cell.Offset(0, -sev5).Value
            Else
        End If
    Next Cell
        For Each Cell In InputRng6
        If Cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            If Len(OutputRng6) > 0 Then OutputRng6.Value = OutputRng6.Value & ","
            OutputRng6.Value = OutputRng6.Value & Cell.Offset(0, -sev6).Value
            Else
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

This is what i'm trying to do if anyone needs a clearer picture
[Picture of what im trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYXpJ.png)

Thanks for the help

Comment: Could not understand your objective clearly. However C is always zero, What do you want the c Value to be if red cell is found?

Comment: c is supposed to +1 to original value once each column is completed but i cant get there for now so i left it out intentionally, i edited it into the second code so you could see where its supposed to be, which part could you not understand ill try ot explain it more clearly,

Comment: Do you need each row to be gone through individually or do you just need to go through each cell? Furthermore, it makes no sense to go through each cell in a cell... For each Column in InputRng is not the column your going through. With this for each you go through each cell in InputRng.

Comment: i would need to go through Each cell in Each column of the desired range but the desired returned value is the row label in the first column ( i Assume you've seen the picture).

Oh what should it be if i want to go through each column in InputRng?

Comment: I cannot see the picture since I'm at work and it is blocked.

Comment: Ive also tried  For Each Column in InputRng.Columns
and For each Cell in Columns.Cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May try

[image]

```
Sub ObtainSCEs()
Dim InputRng As Range
Dim OutputRng As Range
Dim Rw  As Long
Dim Col As Long

xTitleID = "ObtainSCE"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("select data Range:", xTitleID, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set OutputRng = Application.InputBox("select output Range:", xTitleID, Type:=8)
Dim A As Long
Dim B As Long
Dim C As Long

Dim Cell As Range
Dim Column As Range

    For Col = 1 To InputRng.Columns.Count
        For Rw = 1 To InputRng.Rows.Count
        If InputRng(Rw, Col).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
        Valx = InputRng(Rw, 1).Offset(0, -1).Value
               If Len(OutputRng.Offset(0, Col - 1)) > 0 Then
               OutputRng.Offset(0, Col - 1).Value = OutputRng.Offset(0, Col - 1).Value & "," & Valx
               Else
               OutputRng.Offset(0, Col - 1) = Valx
               End If
        End If
     Next Rw
     Next Col

End Sub
```

Input range selection excludes Row labels column, for output range selection of first cell of the destination range will do.

Comment: The reference numbers are all in the same row in the far left while the highlighted values are the highest numbers in each column ( Its data in a pivot table) and my output comes out in one line , would you like me to post the current code that i am using that works but is tedious to use? it might give you a better understanding of what im trying to do

Comment: Edited answer may pl feedback

Comment: its not reading the color and going into the code from Valx and skips straight to Next rw even if the cell is red.

Comment: May use .`DisplayFormat` as in OP in case of conditional formatting. Also Declare  `Valx` ( or assign directly)  and remove unused declarations

Comment: Ok i found out why and got it to work, Thanks for your help , you were missing a display format Before your Interior.color. Thanks so much, just want to know , is it better to use for loops and not for each loops?

Comment: Welcome, I had to skip `DisplayFormat`  as i am using  older version of excel.

Answer (score 0):

This way you go through each column.

```
Sub ObtainSCEs()

Dim InRng As Range
Dim OutRng As Range
BoxTitle = "ObtainSCE"
Set InRng = Application.InputBox("Select Data Input Range", BoxTitle, , Type:=8)
Set OutRng = Application.InputBox("Select Data Output Range", BoxTitle, , Type:=8)

Dim cll As Range
Dim col As Range

For Each col In InRng.Columns
    For Each cll In InRng
        If cll.Column = col.Column Then
            '...
            'whatever you want to do
            '...
        End If
    Next cll
Next col


End Sub
```

Comment: Im getting an error in the (If cll.Column = Col.Column Then)Line It says runtime error 91, object variable or block with block variable not set.